# In LUA get a list of random numbers between a range, but allow x set of duplicates per number

Tags: lua

There is a ton of examples of generating random numbers in LUA that have no duplicates, and just a standard math.random(x,y) can get a set of random whole numbers in a range....

... but I am having trouble finding a set of random numbers between a range, but allowing x amount of duplicates. For my immediate needs I can allow 1 set of duplicates, but it would be great to have code where you can set "duplicate value" to anything for future projects.

**Example :** I want to generate a list of 10 whole numbers between 1-10... each value can be anything between 1-10, but any one number can only be generated and added to the list twice.

**Example Result:** 1,1,2,4,5,5,7,7,8,9

In this example result math.random() tried to spit out 3 or more of the same number, but the code makes it go back and try again if it has already produced 2 of the same number.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Generate a sequential list of non-random numbers between a range with
  no duplicates.
- Add them to a table, but add each number X amount of times, where X
  is the total amount of duplicates allowed. So we know have a table x
  times as long with each individual number listed X amount of times.
- Shuffle the table, or generate a list of random numbers or both.
- Then simply extract the numbers from the table using the generated
  numbers as the numeric key value for the "duplicate" table.
- You can store anything at those key values so this works for
  anything.. not just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "merge trick":

1. Create "unical" array of numbers for 5 **(10/number of dublicats)** elements: 1,2,5,7,9
2. Repeate #1
3. Merge arrays.

You can generalize it with paramers of minValue, maxValue, totalNumber, numberOfDublicates, but will need to little more code for handling 10/3 problems and maxValue < totalNumber.